# I need help about apache AWS server error

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is my error log:

```
[Sat Apr 09 00:00:02.545833 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 1078:tid 139965531106176] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Apr 09 00:00:02.546331 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1078:tid 139965531106176] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1n configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 09 00:00:02.546343 2022] [core:notice] [pid 1078:tid 139965531106176] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/bitnami/apache/bin/httpd -f /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf'
[Sat Apr 09 02:41:12.544588 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1202:tid 139964822038272] [client 17.121.113.180:39176] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: Division by zero in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/inc/class-fusion-images.php on line 965PHP message: PHP Warning: Division by zero in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/inc/class-fusion-images.php on line 969PHP message: PHP Warning: Division by zero in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/inc/class-fusion-images.php on line 965PHP message: PHP Warning: Division by zero in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/inc/class-fusion-images.php on line 969'
[Sat Apr 09 09:31:44.420000 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1078:tid 139965531106176] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Apr 09 09:31:57.487091 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 15475:tid 140632821046144] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Apr 09 09:31:57.497338 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 15476:tid 140632821046144] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Apr 09 09:31:57.498712 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 15476:tid 140632821046144] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1n configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 09 09:31:57.498743 2022] [core:notice] [pid 15476:tid 140632821046144] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/bitnami/apache/bin/httpd -f /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf'
[Sat Apr 09 12:33:50.506173 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 15801:tid 140632135796480] [client 66.249.66.86:38757] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: Division by zero in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/inc/class-fusion-images.php on line 965PHP message: PHP Warning: Division by zero in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/inc/class-fusion-images.php on line 969PHP message: PHP Warning: Di
```

Comment: `Division by zero in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/inc/class-fusion-images.php on line 965` is a code problem you need to fix. You may want to start at https://theme-fusion.com/forums/topic/warning-division-by-zero-error/ and ensure you've updated your plugins.

Comment: What error? What problem do you see?